# Run a jar File from java program

Tags: java, jar, runtime, executable-jar

I am trying to execute jar files from another Java program. I am using the following code :

```
      try {
          Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
          runtime.exec("path upto jar");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception occured" + ex);
      }
```

But its not working. I tried google and it gave me the examples using ProcessBuilder, but that is not working either.

Comment: Does your argument to `exec` include the necessary `[path]/java -jar` bits?

Comment: And use `ProcessBuilder`, it handles space in commands/parameters better

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using **ProcessBuilder(java.lang.ProcessBuilder)** will solve your problem. Syntax is as follows -

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "absolute path upto jar");
Process p = pb.start();
```

You can redirent input/output/error to/from files as follows

```
File commands = new File("absolute path to inputs file");
File dirOut = new File("absolute path to outputs file");
File dirErr = new File("absolute path to error file");

dirProcess.redirectInput(commands);
dirProcess.redirectOutput(dirOut);
dirProcess.redirectError(dirErr);
```

Answer (score 9):

First suggestion/recommendation is to use ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime. Here is what you can try:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "./jarpath/yourjar.jar");
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String s = "";
while((s = in.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(s);
}
int status = p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Exited with status: " + status);
```

Comment: If the while loop terminates with the process, is the waitFor() really required?

Answer (score 2):

You can run a jar file from where ever you want by using only this one line code.

```
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("D:/FormsDesktop.jar"));
```

where

```
new File("your path to jar")
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks.