# alternate way to run jar file

Tags: java, oracle, jar

I have to run my .jar file on clients Oracle server. I do not have the access of command prompt through which a jar file is usually run. Is there any way that I can include my jar file in the java code and it runs on the server?

We normally use `loadjava -u username/password d:\jarfilename`. I need to perform similar operation on Oracle server to which I do not have a direct access.

Comment: Possibly the following link has an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985036/run-a-jar-file-from-java-program

Comment: We normally use 
loadjava -u username/password d:\jarfilename. I need to perform similar operation on Oracle server to which I do not have a direct access

Comment: You may create a script double-click enabled in which you call something like "java -jar ..."

Comment: You can also run it from the Oracle client side as `loadjava -u username/password@database d:\jarfilename`. Necessary grants silently assumed in the example.